# Verifying signature on android in-app purchase message in Python on Google App Engine

Tags: python, android, google-app-engine, in-app-purchase

The sample application on the android developers site validates the purchase json using java code.  Has anybody had any luck working out how to validate the purchase in python.  In particular in GAE?

The following are the relevant excerpts from the android in-app billing [example program](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_integrate.html#billing-download). This is what would need to be converted to python using [PyCrypto](http://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/) which was re-written to be completely python by Google and is the only Security lib available on app engine.  Hopefully Google is cool with me using the excerpts below.

```
private static final String KEY_FACTORY_ALGORITHM = "RSA";
private static final String SIGNATURE_ALGORITHM = "SHA1withRSA";
String base64EncodedPublicKey = "your public key here";

PublicKey key = Security.generatePublicKey(base64EncodedPublicKey);
verified = Security.verify(key, signedData, signature);

public static PublicKey generatePublicKey(String encodedPublicKey) {
    try {
        byte[] decodedKey = Base64.decode(encodedPublicKey);
        KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance(KEY_FACTORY_ALGORITHM);
        return keyFactory.generatePublic(new X509EncodedKeySpec(decodedKey));
    } catch ...
    }
}
public static boolean verify(PublicKey publicKey, String signedData, String signature) {
    if (Consts.DEBUG) {
        Log.i(TAG, "signature: " + signature);
    }
    Signature sig;
    try {
        sig = Signature.getInstance(SIGNATURE_ALGORITHM);
        sig.initVerify(publicKey);
        sig.update(signedData.getBytes());
        if (!sig.verify(Base64.decode(signature))) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Signature verification failed.");
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    } catch ...
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I'm not going to post this as an answer because I can't tell if its what your looking for exactly, but try this [link - Google Code](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/rpc.html), it shows how to write a GAE app that will respond with JSON, which you could modify to provide your validation I suppose

Answer (score 15):

Here's how i did it:

```
from Crypto.Hash import SHA
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from Crypto.Signature import PKCS1_v1_5
from base64 import b64decode

def chunks(s, n):
    for start in range(0, len(s), n):
        yield s[start:start+n]

def pem_format(key):
    return '\n'.join([
        '-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----',
        '\n'.join(chunks(key, 64)),
        '-----END PUBLIC KEY-----'
    ])

def validate_purchase(publicKey, signedData, signature):
    key = RSA.importKey(pem_format(publicKey))
    verifier = PKCS1_v1_5.new(key)
    data = SHA.new(signedData)
    sig = b64decode(signature)
    return verifier.verify(data, sig)
```

This assumes that `publicKey` is your base64 encoded Google Play Store key on one line as you get it from the Developer Console.

For people who rather use m2crypto, `validate_purchase()` would change to:

```
from M2Crypto import RSA, BIO, EVP
from base64 import b64decode

# pem_format() as above

def validate_purchase(publicKey, signedData, signature):
    bio = BIO.MemoryBuffer(pem_format(publicKey))
    rsa = RSA.load_pub_key_bio(bio)
    key = EVP.PKey()
    key.assign_rsa(rsa)
    key.verify_init()
    key.verify_update(signedData)
    return key.verify_final(b64decode(signature)) == 1
```

Comment: I have to add following line in `validate_purchase(publicKey,signedData,signature)` function to make it work:
`signedData=signedData.encode("utf8")`

Comment: Thank you, you made my day! You could also transform the Google license to a valid public key like so: `openssl enc -base64 -d -in publickey.base64 -A | openssl rsa -inform DER -pubin > publickey.pem`

Answer (score 7):

I finally figured out that your base64 encoded public key from Google Play is an X.509 subjectPublicKeyInfo DER SEQUENCE, and that the signature scheme is RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5 and not RSASSA-PSS. If you have [PyCrypto](https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/) installed, it's actually quite easy:

```
import base64
from Crypto.Hash import SHA
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from Crypto.Signature import PKCS1_v1_5

# Your base64 encoded public key from Google Play.
_PUBLIC_KEY_BASE64 = "YOUR_BASE64_PUBLIC_KEY_HERE"
# Key from Google Play is a X.509 subjectPublicKeyInfo DER SEQUENCE.
_PUBLIC_KEY = RSA.importKey(base64.standard_b64decode(_PUBLIC_KEY_BASE64))

def verify(signed_data, signature_base64):
    """Returns whether the given data was signed with the private key."""

    h = SHA.new()
    h.update(signed_data)
    # Scheme is RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5.
    verifier = PKCS1_v1_5.new(_PUBLIC_KEY)
    # The signature is base64 encoded.
    signature = base64.standard_b64decode(signature_base64)
    return verifier.verify(h, signature)
```

Answer (score 2):

Now that we're in 2016, here's how to do it with `cryptography`:

```
import base64
import binascii

from cryptography.exceptions import InvalidSignature
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes, serialization
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import padding


class RSAwithSHA1:
    def __init__(self, public_key):
        # the public key google gives you is in DER encoding
        # let cryptography handle it for you
        self.public_key = serialization.load_der_public_key(
            base64.b64decode(public_key), backend=default_backend()
        )

    def verify(self, data, signature):
        """
        :param str data: purchase data
        :param str signature: data signature
        :return: True signature verification passes or False otherwise
        """
        # note the signature is base64 encoded
        signature = base64.b64decode(signature.encode())
        # as per https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_reference.html
        # the signature uses "the RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5 scheme"
        verifier = self.public_key.verifier(
            signature, padding.PKCS1v15(), hashes.SHA1(),
        )
        verifier.update(data.encode())
        try:
            verifier.verify()
        except InvalidSignature:
            return False
        else:
            return True
```