# Google Play Billing Response Signature verification

Tags: android, encryption, google-play, rsa, sign

I'm developing an android app that uses in-app purchases. After the user makes a purchase, the play store sends a response as a JSON string. That response looks something like this (Without the sensitive information redacted, of course):

```
{  
   "type":"android-playstore",
   "id":"<My Application ID>",
   "purchaseToken":"<The Purchase Token>",
   "receipt":{  
      "orderId":"<The Order ID>",
      "packageName":"com.example.skeleton",
      "productId":"credit.basic",
      "purchaseTime":1436546971245,
      "purchaseState":0,
      "purchaseToken":"<The Purchase Token>"
   },
   "signature":"Im27prAnxYwdRoug..."
}
```

The [Google Play billing security documentation](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html#billing-security) states that

> Google Play signs the JSON string that contains the response data for a purchase order. Google Play uses the private key that is associated with your application in the Developer Console to create this signature.

I'm not that good with crypto but my understanding is that RSA signing works by taking the SHA1 hash of the string to be signed, then encrypting that with the private key to produce a signature. When one wants to verify the origin of the string, the signature is decrypted with the public key (proving that it was encrypted with the private key) and the decrypted hash is compared with the hash of the message to see if they match.

However, there's a problem here. The signature itself is contained within the JSON string sent to my application. You can't change the string after it's been signed, so when Google says that they "Sign the JSON string that contains the response data" they can't mean the entire JSON string I received. They have to sign some portion of the string and append the signature to that. My problem is that **I can't figure out what portion of the string was signed.** Using the signature verification implementation described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5440550/verifying-signature-on-android-in-app-purchase-message-in-python-on-google-app-e) I tried verifying the JSON string with the signature property removed, without the brackets, with only the receipt portion, etc. Just for good measure, I tried the entire string, signature included. I can't seem to find any portion of this JSON string that can be cryptographically verified with my public key. Is there some portion of the string that I should be using, or do I just not understand how signatures work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And as often happens, within 30 minutes of posting on StackOverflow, I figured it out.

The problem stems from the fact that I'm developing this application in PhoneGap, and using the [in-app-purchasing plugin](https://github.com/j3k0/cordova-plugin-purchase) to perform this transaction. The plugin is lying to me slightly when it gives me that JSON string above. Google sends the response data in one JSON string and the signature in another, while the plugin wraps it up into the single string above. The correct way to do this is to verify the 'receipt' item, as shown below.

```
{  
      "orderId":"<The Order ID>",
      "packageName":"com.example.skeleton",
      "productId":"credit.basic",
      "purchaseTime":1436546971245,
      "purchaseState":0,
      "purchaseToken":"<The Purchase Token>"
 }
```

The python implementation listed in the question verifies the signature of this JSON string.

Answer (score 5):

For anyone who are using java to verify the google pay signature via public key, **DO** pay attention: 
The signed data is a json string **ONLY** **ONLY** **ONLY** contains the `orderId`, `packageName`, `productId`, `purchaseTime`, `purchaseState`, `purchaseToken`.

For example:
If the response data from google pay is like below:

```
{
    "nameValuePairs": {
        "orderId": "your.order.id",
        "packageName": "your.package.name",
        "productId": "your.product.id",
        "purchaseTime": 1526476218113,
        "purchaseState": 0,
        "purchaseToken": "your.purchase.token"
    }
}
```

Then the signed data your will checking the signature on is **ONLY** like below:

```
{
    "orderId": "your.order.id",
    "packageName": "your.package.name",
    "productId": "your.product.id",
    "purchaseTime": 1526476218113,
    "purchaseState": 0,
    "purchaseToken": "your.purchase.token"
}
```

Hope this post be helpful to anyone whoever need it.